# Create a not resizable window with XLib

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I want to create a not resizable window in X11, so I have to set *override_redirect* window attribute to True. However, I still want the window to interact with all the other windows and to be shown in the side slot (where the currently opened windows are showed). I want my window to be overlapped by other windows and to be switched with `Alt+Tab`.

The example of such an application is [Telegram Desktop](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop). It hasn't got default window decorations, but still looks like a fully functional X11 app.[image]

Comment: Or where can I learn more about this

Comment: I would expect this to be in https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html protocol but don't see anything describing "hey wm I want everything except for window decorations which I'll handle myself". it might be the only option is to handle resize on app side completely